# jQuery not selecting absolute positioned cloned <div>'s

Tags: jquery, html, css

(Please find code link at bottom of the question)

I have been developing a radial menu for web. However I've hit a snag and been stuck on it for a few hours and no matter what I do I can't seem to be able to get any response from any selector's I have tried.

I have been able to do this...

```
$(document).on('mouseover' function() {
    $('#selector0").remove();
});
```

And that managed to remove one of my generated elements.

however I tried to use this code and it doesnt work.

```
$("#selector0").on('mouseover' function() {
    $("#selector0").remove();
});
```

I also tried to send my self an alert which also failed. I also tried selecting all the cloned items by there class which also failed. I have thought that maybe it has something to do with the **Position: Absolute**. Was thinking maybe because of the jQuery can't pick up on the mouse events to that item?

If someone could help me figure this out I'd be extremely grateful. I have coded a demo version of what I'm doing on jsFiddle so people can go check out code and mess with it there.

http://jsfiddle.net/cjtpB/13/

Comment: use class instead of id, you have duplicate id in your page. Can you make a jsfiddle with the class, i know it doesn't work yet, but you just can't duplicate id...

Comment: the ID is not getting duplicated. if you look at the code its creating a new id for each clone. #selctor0, #selector1, etc. creating a new number each time it loops. However it is generating a genreic class for them all

Comment: Will using .live() help? Take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657060/removing-a-dom-element-using-jquery-not-working

Comment: click more than 10 times and you'll see the id get duplicated

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. That won't happen in the final release since the menu will only be generated on a per click basis then destroyed. SO those repeats should not appear. Thanks for catching that for me though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've encountered a lot of problems with matching dynamically added elements.

What I usually do is using `body` in the select instead of the element name, then place the element name in the function call:

```
$('body').on('click', '#elementName', function () {
    alert('Clicked!');
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Just tried that in my code now and it's selecting it perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If your code is exaclty like you show, there is a problem with quoting

```
$('#selector0').remove();
```

Replace the `"` by `'` at the end of the selector

Comment: @sureshatta: because opening and closing quotes must match, he opened with single quotes and closed with double quotes

Comment: That was a mistake in the post. just fixed it. mistake is not found in code.